# Java using a parsed xml in different classes

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I was wondering how I can pass a parsed xml in different java classes within the same project. For example, I have

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory. newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse("Companies.xml");
    etc.
```

And I can parse through it and do what I need to do in main, but I would like to be able to split up this process into different classes. I would have a class for employees, departments, etc. But when I do this in main I can simply say, 
     NodeList EmployeeList = document.getElementsByTagName("employees");. But if I were to try this in a different class it wouldnt have access to document. So how can I use the document in a different class, or do I have to create a new "document" file in every class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass in the Document object to the constructor of the new class. Then it can parse the elements it needs.

Alternatively you could use a Java Object parser that can convert to and from XML for you.

[Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What would the data type be of the document parameter?

Comment: @user3071909 `Document document`

Comment: @ankur-singhal  It says it can't find symbol

Comment: @user3071909 are your imports correct, refer this, i created the utility [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.jp/2014/11/java-objects-to-xml-and-xml-to-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Best would be

1.) To have a constructor in each class, accepting the `Document Object as argument`.

2.) Use the Document Object in other classes to get the values.

3.) Or you can directly convert from `XML to JAVA Object` or `Java Object to XML`, follow these links.

[link1](http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example) and [link2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/convert-java-object-xml-and)

Comment: What would be the data type of the parameter document?